# Обновить "текущую" версию Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu

Ubuntu Server 18.04.5 LTS. Необходимо обновить до последней версии 18.XX.X (не до 20-ой).

Как правильно это сделать?

Пробовал так:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
do-release-upgrade
```

В итоге получил 20ую версию.

Comment: Просто не делайте do-release-upgrade

Comment: Ну а 18.04.5 это и так самая последняя версия тут